# Resource.Id does not contain a definition for list

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin/Android. I am developing a Xamarin Android application, and I have the below .axml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">

  <ListView
       android:minWidth="25px"
       android:minHeight="25px"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@android:id/list" >    
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In an Activity class that I am writing, I am trying to get a reference to this ListView using the below code:

```
FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
```

Visual Studio raises a compilation error "Resource.Id does not contain a definition for list." However, if I use

> android:id="@+id/list"

as the Id of the ListView, the compilation error goes away, but I get another error *"Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"* at **SetContentView** call in the Activity class's OnCreate.

Answer (score 0):

> Resource.Id does not contain a definition for list

You need to define it in your `.axml` file as you write before:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'" at SetContentView call in the Activity class's OnCreate.

Could you please check whether you have used the `SetContentView` in your `Activity`?

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
    }
}
```